# C# project additional output path

Tags: c#, msbuild, build, project-management

In project file, normally we can see the following for setting the project output path. Now I am wondering if there is a way to set additional output path. i.e., the built binaries will be copied to the additional path as well.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be trivial to add a post-build event to your project/solution configuration, which copies the files from the original build location to your specified new one. Go to your project properties, and under "Build Events" add the following to your post-build event command line:

```
xcopy /E $(ProjectDir)bin\Release\ [pathToMyDestination]
```

As an aside, I'm guessing you want to publish your release build to a host. In that case it's worth looking into *continuous integration* software, which gives you powerful capabilities. We've used several and are currently using Team City (free).